# How to get Global ip of Android Phone

Tags: android, ip

i want to use sockets for making audio calls, for which i need global ip address of phone i am using this code but it gives me the local ip

```
    WifiManager wim= (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> l =  wim.getConfiguredNetworks(); 
WifiConfiguration wc = l.get(0);
IP=Formatter.formatIpAddress(wim.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

what i should add in this code to get Global IP address ?

Comment: _global ip address_: you mean the gateway IP? Or do you mean the WAN IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an Http Request to http://ifconfig.me/all.json or ifconfig.me/all.xml if you prefer XML -  you will get a lot of info's about your WAN connection

Comment: thanks its helpful too but i used http://www.exip.org/api.php , it only gives you your IP.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to write a client that connects to a server, and have the server respond back with what IP it sees the client as. There's no standard way for a client to detect its outside IP address, since there can be arbitrary amounts of NATting going on.

Comment: what if phone is connected via WIFI, still i cant get the external IP ..?

Comment: Only if you have some service on the outside to reply back with the IP. The wifi could be behind several NAT layers.